# What is the filepicker.io regular expression style?

Tags: regex, security, filepicker.io

I am trying to make my filepicker.io uploads more secure, but my regular expressions in the path option of the policy cause a 403 forbidden error. I guess my regular expression style is wrong. If anybody can tell me what regex-style the filepicker-server expects I would be very grateful!

I tried those basic `.*` all-paths-allowed-policies for debugging, all of them fail with 403:

```
{"call":["pick","store"],"expiry":1378734111,"path":"/.*/"}
{"call":["pick","store"],"expiry":1378734111,"path":"#.*#"}
{"call":["pick","store"],"expiry":1378734111,"path":".*"}
```

Of course, more complex regular expressions also fail. The [filepicker docs](https://developers.inkfilepicker.com/docs/security/) say, it should be perl-like, so as I understand perl-like-regex, at least the first one should work! Thanks for any hint! Btw, if I drop the path option, everything works fine (but not very secure).

Comment: Should the path be quoted ?

Comment: Could you link to that part in the docs where it talks about that path option?

Comment: @amon They just ask an immediately leave away, here it is [docs](https://developers.inkfilepicker.com/docs/security/).

Comment: Thx 4 the responses, here's the link to the security-docs with the path option: https://developers.inkfilepicker.com/docs/security/ - If I remove the `"` I just get a CORS error since it's not interpreted as a regexp string anymore.

Comment: I don't know if the path should be quoted, but if i leave the quotes away I get the CORS error. They really tell few about how the regexp should be delivered, I guessed as string..